# What's this anime with talking monsters?

Tags: monster-rancher

This anime is like Pokemon or Digimon. It has various talking monsters, who are friends with some humans and travel around. One of the monsters is kind of a big wolf. There is also big rabbit which stands with two feet and is about the size of a human. Both of them can talk, and the wolf always says something like "I'm gonna eat you!" to the rabbit. I watched it in early 2000s or something around that time. Does anyone know this anime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

The show you are looking for is called "[Monster Rancher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_(anime))".

The name of the wolf you are probably referring to is "Tiger" and the rabbit's name is "Hare".